# Finding matrix value where there is no solution, infinitely many, or unique

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the linear system,

$3x_{1}-6\alpha x_{2}=2$

$2\alpha x_{1}-x_{2}=-2/3$

Find values of $\alpha$ where the system has no solution, infinitely many solutions, and a unique situation, if it exists.

I put this into an augmented matrix:

$\left[\begin{matrix}
    3 & -6a & 2 \\[6pt]
    2a & -1 &-2/3
\end{matrix}\right]$

THe reduction is quite simple, I end up with:

$\left[\begin{matrix}
    1 & a & -2/3 \\[6pt]
    a & 1 &-2/3
\end{matrix}\right]$

But what I am having trouble figuring out from here is what values of alpha where there would be no solutions, infinitely many, or a unique solution. How would you take the matrix here to get that result?

Comment: @moo makes sense, moving alpha out. But I am still having difficulty figuring out no solution, unique, or infinitely?

Comment: @Moo yes, when a=1/2 there are infinite solutions, when a=-1/2 the solution is 4/3. Is that correct?

Comment: @moo I see it now. a=-1/2 infinite solutions. a=1/2 no solution. But what about a unique solution? Anytime a does not equal 1/2 or -1/2?

Comment: @moo makes sense. Thanks for the help.